# TypeError: document.querySelectorAll is not a function Stripe

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

I am getting the following error in while implementing Stripe.

> TypeError: document.querySelectorAll is not a function
> at findScript (node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/dist/stripe.js:9:26)
> at/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/dist/stripe.js:75:20
> at new Promise ()
> at loadScript (/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/dist/stripe.js:57:19)
> at/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/dist/stripe.js:113:10
> at runMicrotasks ()
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

Sample Code

```
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";

const PUBLIC_KEY = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY;
const stripeTestPromise = loadStripe(PUBLIC_KEY);

<Elements stripe={stripeTestPromise}>
  <PaymentForm ref={paymentRef} helpRequest={helpRequest} callback={callback} />
</Elements>;
```

Comment: Yes, there is no `document` in Node.js, it's not a browser. Not exactly sure what you are doing though (the code you provided is a mix of Node.js and HTML?), I can be mistaken

Comment: @JeremyThille I am getting error in building app Its React JS code

Comment: The `loadStripe` function [returns a `Promise`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js#loadstripe) (that you'll need to `await`). Also, your React component is not actually returning anything. Wrap the `<Elements />` component in a `return` statement.